# ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, importerror

I am trying to build a model using reinforcement learning, and I keep running into the same ImportError. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both tensorflow and keras. I have tried the other solution from other forums where you set "from keras import **version**" yet still no luck.

It keeps giving "from tensorflow.keras import **version** as KERAS_VERSION" along with the ImportError message.

Note: I have latest versions installed. Don't know what to try. Help would be greatly appreciated!

When I try to import the keras dependency through tensorflow, as so:

from tensorflow import keras

It doesnt seem to import,

Even if I try to use "tensorflow.keras" it does not work. I get:

Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you imported keras from the tensorflow library instead of importing it directly from keras library:

```
from keras import __version__ as KERAS_VERSION

print(KERAS_VERSION)
```

on 2.14.* and 2.15.* tensorflow versions   `tf.keras.__version__` is not defined.
it only works on older versions.

Comment: Oh ok got it, I had the latest versions of tensorflow installed thats why. Appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I want to believe you have installed tensor flow first. If you haven’t, do this:
“pip install tensorflow”

Then

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

TensorFlow requires Python 3.6–3.9

If all doesn’t work,try creating a new environment:

python -m venv tf-env
source tf-env/bin/activate  # for Windows  `tf-env\Scripts\activate`

Comment: Yes tensorflow was already installed prior to this, and currently the version of Python I have installed is 3.11. Will try creating a new environment. Thanks!

Comment: update: this whole time I installed the modules globally instead of in a virtual environment. So I went in my directory and pip installed the modules there. Another reason I think I got this issue is because I may have had the wrong python interpreter. Which is why I probably was not able to use "tensorflow.keras" without it giving the error message. In any case, thanks for the answer!